# Center each text horizontally and vertically to its image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how center each text horizontally and vertically to its corresponding image with what I have so far.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="content">CYREX
    <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/qXPbx+" class="thumbnils" />
</div>
<div class="content">HITMAN
    <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/qXPbx+" class="thumbnils" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.content{
    width: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.thumbnils{width: 70%;}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9z1mabbg/)

Comment: Is it supposed to be `.thumbnils` or `.thumbnails`?

Comment: Do you want the text to be above the image?

Comment: @DineiA.Rockenbach thanks, yes text above the image.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin: :) that's a typo... not too bothered about it though :) thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the text in spans and add this to the css

```
span 
{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: calc(50% - 10px); /* half of font size */
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep your HTML markup, you can use like this:

```css
.content{
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.content span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.thumbnils{
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <span>CYREX</span>
    <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/qXPbx+" class="thumbnils" />
</div>
<div class="content">
    <span>HITMAN</span>
    <input type="image" src="http://img42.com/qXPbx+" class="thumbnils" />
</div>
```

But if you don't need to bother about IE8< compatibility and those are just images, you could use like this:

```css
.content {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: url("http://img42.com/qXPbx+") no-repeat center center;
    background-size:contain;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span>CYREX</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <span>HITMAN</span>
</div>
```

But be aware of the [`background-size` browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your HTML and you don't mind using css3 you may use this CSS:

```
.content{
    width: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.content span {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
.thumbnils{
    width: 70%; 
}
```

Taking into account I have just wrapped your text inside a `span` tag so I could call it with css.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9z1mabbg/2/)**

Comment: That's why I said "and you don't mind using css3"... Some days I really think my english sucks. Is it really that bad?

Comment: Oh, no, sorry. My fault, I misunderstood you.